# is there any method to check if both of the label text interupt together?

Tags: ios, swift

Now current i am placing the text into the table cell, however, i wish to detect that if two label , if one of the label text hit another one, (do something)

May i ask if the ios is able to achieve this with any method?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the label's frames intersect each other:

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(label1.frame, label2.frame) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @JanGreve Right, forgot about that.